# How to display the last four blog posts using JSON API in div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress, api

How do I display the latest four blog post WordPress API in HTML

HTML:

```html
<div id="content" class="content"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("https://startupet.com/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts", function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });  
  })
</script>
```

I'm getting image post and title

JSON file: https://startupet.com/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

Comment: What have you tried for this?

Comment: use datatable in frontend or modify query as a pagination in backend

Comment: @RinkeshGolwalaI almost do not know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `slice` with a negative number to get the element from the end of the array.

In this example , dummy api is returning a response and `slice(-4)` is used to get the last 4 elements, then iterate that array and create the dom

```js
$.getJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", function(data) {
  let string = '';
  data.slice(-4).forEach(function(item) {
    string += `<div>${item.title}</div>`
  })
  $("#content").append(string)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" class="content">
</div>
```

Comment: I can not access post photos. I do not see the path of the photos. please help

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array based on the timestamp and slice it with the number of items you require.

Next is to iterate through the result and display however you want in the html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON( "https://startupet.com/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts", 
function(data) {
const result = data.sort((a,b) => (a.date > b.date)).slice(Math.max(data.length - 4, 1)); 
console.log(result); // Your Result contains the last 4 posts sorted by date
});  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" class="content">
</div>
```

Comment: I can not access post photos. I do not see the path of the photos. please help

Comment: Is it present in the json response?

Comment: I do not know . I can not find